# Maven / Spring: AopNamespaceUtils NoSuchMethod Error

Tags: java, spring, maven

Using Maven to build my project under windows works fine, but when I build it under Linux I get a `NoSuchMethodError` regarding one of the spring libs.

I am guessing it is something to do with class loader differences cross-platform and somewhere in my dependencies and I may have the same class twice but windows is loading one while linux loads the other?

Has anyone come across this problem before, or have any advice on how I can debug this error further?

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:             
org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
 at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConf
```

[Stack Trace Pastie](http://www.pastie.org/2061718)
[POM.xml Pastie](http://www.pastie.org/2061741)

Comment: you can find the anwser here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20981458/3343174

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your spring dependencies have too many different versions:

> org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
>   org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.0.8:compile
>   org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile

Make all spring dependencies have the same version (preferably 3.0.5.RELEASE)

Comment: Thanks, the dependencies for other libraries were pulling in incompatible versions of these libs as transitative(?) dependencies.  Adding explicit `<dependency>` tags for the libraries meant that I could pin the versions to the most recent releases which got rid of the runtime error.

Comment: Is it `non-trivial` to change, in this example, `spring-beans` and `spring-aop` to use `3.0.5.RELEASE`? I presume there's regression testing that needs to happen to ensure that the new versions don't break the software.