# NoSuchMethodError when Running Java App

Tags: java

When I try to run my `java` console app, I see the following errors on `Red Hat 5`, but not on `Ubuntu`.

Another StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333684/maven-spring-aopnamespaceutils-nosuchmethod-error#comment24284713_6333684) mentions not to mix versions of `spring` 2 and 3.

But I ran `find [where I run app - includes classpath] | grep spring | grep 3` and saw 0 results. As a result, I believe it's not a `spring` version issue.

```
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
> Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL
> location
> [classpath:/org/eurekastreams/server/conf/applicationContext-model.xml]
> Offending resource: class path resource [conf/applicationContext.xml];
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
> Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource
> [org/eurekastreams/server/conf/applicationContext-model.xml]; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.aop.config.
AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary
(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;
Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
```

**EDIT**

Added stack trace:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V`

After running `mvn dependency:tree`, I saw a few versions of `spring-aop.jar`:

```
$grep "spring-aop" mvn_dependency_tree.txt 
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.0.8:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.0.8:provided
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.0.8:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.5.4:compile
```

Would these different versions of `spring-aop` maybe explain the `AOP` error from the stack trace I added?

Comment: I suspect your problem is still multiple versions of Spring on classpath, just maybe not versions 2 & 3.

Comment: Agreed, it seems very likely you have a version conflict. You don't provide enough information to provide any input beyond that.

Comment: Hmm. If I'm running the app from the same directory and `$CLASSPATH` on `Ubuntu` and `RHEL`, how could this error occur for one, but not the other?

Comment: NSMEs only happen when you compile against a version of a library that has the method you are trying to call but then run with a different version of that library that doesn't have that method you compiled against.  Is it possible you have more than one version of spring on your classpath?  Java arbitrarily chooses versions of jars/classes on your classpath if more than one have the same class name.

Comment: `multiple versions of spring` means different versions of the same `jar`? Example: I have `spring-core-2.5.5.jar` on my `$CLASSPATH`, but also `spring-support-2.0.8.jar`. Is that OK?

Comment: @Kevin can you update your post with the list of all the jars you have with your app?

Comment: @Kevin Depends on what the actual dependencies are.

Comment: @Kevin look at http://mvnrepository.com/, there you can see the version dependency of your jars.

Comment: Or use Maven, since that's what it's for: `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: I updated my question after running `mvn dependency:tree` and looking at results. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like version 2.0.8 of spring-aop is the culprit here.

What you need to do is examine the dependency tree output (not grep it) to find out which 'parent' jars have a dependency on this version and hence are pulling it onto your classpath. Either by removing or upgrading the version of the parent jars, you should be able to clean the classpath, leaving behind version 2.5.4.

Once you have done this, rebuild and run your application.

Here is more info on dependency tree:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: Actually, I spoke to the guy who wrote this app. He informed me that there's an `RPM` that, once installed, will run as a service. It specifies the `$CLASSPATH`, among other config for running the `java` app.