# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

web.xml

```
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">

   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value></init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

sdnext-servlet.xml

```
<beans 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/resources/database.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.anand" />


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="jspViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.anand.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>    
            </props>
      </property>

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**I have written all the classes which i followed the below url:
http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-crud-example.html#.VDRBOvldWJF

Please help me to solve the error. Thank you
**
**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>EmployeeCRUD</groupId>
  <artifactId>EmployeeCRUD</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-jakarta-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-repository</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error I am getting:

```
12:06:40.521 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54) ~[spring-dao-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:143) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Oct 06, 2014 12:06:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: env? are you using maven, jpa, spring what else?

Comment: Show your spring dependencies you have in your pom.xml

Comment: You are following a Spring tutorial that configures your app for Spring 3, whereas you are pulling in Spring 4 dependencies in your pom. I would suggest looking for a tutorial that uses Spring 4, Hibernate 4 since these are the recent versions of their respective frameworks.

Comment: You are mixing spring versions... DOn't. YOu are mixing jars from 2.0.8, 4.0.6 and 4.1.0. Remove all the non 4.1.0 jars or make sure that you use the 4.1.0 equivalent of those.

Answer (score 3):

Remove spring-dao dependency. it is not required in spring 4.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**[Reason]** because it was calling a method `method A` which is not available in `spring 4` libraries. And due to some how higher priority of this dependency `spring-dao`, `spring 4` was calling a method `method B` from this dependency instead of from related `spring 4` dependency. `Method B` is now modified in `spring 4` and no more calling of `method A` from `method B`. So `method A` is removed from `spring 4`. As `spring-dao` is not part of `spring 4` and doesn't know that `method A` is no more available so was getting crashed.

Comment: Could you elaborate why removing this dependency would solve the `NoSuchMethodError`?

Comment: This solution would not solve this exact problem, but it would solve a different error which rises when using the `@Transactional` annotation. That said, check this link [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/746322-transactional-compile-error)

Comment: I have no idea why, but this actually solved my problem. I actually tried this solution out of mere frustration from the past two days of being stuck with this error, and this solved my problem!

Comment: reason is attached with answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different versions of the spring framework, as can be seen from the stacktrace: 4.1.0.RELEASE and 4.0.6.RELEASE. This is also configured incorrectly in your pom.xml. Just correct the pom.xml to use a single version for all spring dependencies and you should be fine.

Comment: Actually he is mixing 3 versions, there is also a 2.0.8 version in  there.

Comment: Make that 4. There is version 1.0.0 also in there. Although the point has been made. No mixing of framework versions!

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to use hibernate 4 then:

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"

in your session factory.

Your transaction manager as well:

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"

Well - there's more. You've set up your DispatcherServlet but if you're going to use spring in a web app you'll need a ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Put your bean definitions in the spring.xml - you can leave your sdnext-servlet.xml pretty bare bones.

Comment: thanks for all your comments, Now I get the different error.error message org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 64; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Answer (score 1):

Removing spring-dao dependency will indeed solve your issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

spring-dao has been superseded by spring-tx see Spring's documentation on What's new in Spring 2.0 and 2.5? section 2.7.1.2. Jar packaging in Spring 2.5. You will note that both the [spring-tx api](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils.html) and [spring-dao api](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceUtils.html) both contain the AopNamespaceUtils class with the overloaded registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary method. It is however only in [spring-dao api that the class has a version of that accepts an object as the second parameter. The call is being made reflectively by Spring the expectation of finding a method with an object as the second parameter as present in spring-dao. However the spring-tx class gets picked up and that does not have a method with an Object as the second parameter hence you get the exception below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54) ~[spring-dao-2.0.8.jar:2.0.8]
```

Thanks to Sheikh Abdul Wahid above who sent me down the right path.