# Upgrading to JDK8 and Spring 4.3.11

Tags: spring, java-8, weblogic

I git this Error when I try to deploy my SOAP service to weblogic

```
2017-12-08 13:52:32,502 INFO  scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor::shutdown(150)  - Shutting down ExecutorService
2017-12-08 13:52:32,503 ERROR transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet::initServletBean(502)  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:98)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:86)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:660)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:600)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1979)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1956)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1846)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor;)V
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.buildAdvice(AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.<init>(AsyncAnnotationAdvisor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 63 more
2017-12-08 13:52:32,522 INFO  context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext::doClose(1020)  - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Dec 08 13:52:17 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Please note I am using:

```
  <spring.version>4.3.11.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
  <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
  <spring.ldap.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.ldap.version>
  <spring.data.commons.version>1.12.3.RELEASE</spring.data.commons.version>
  <spring.ws.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
  <spring.oauth2.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</spring.oauth2.version>
```

I know the error exists in the **spring-aop** which is 4.3.11 as well, which is not compatible with spring 4, but my goal from this is to upgrade my project to spring 4 ultimately and use JDK8. [one relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981387/nosuchmethoderrorregisterautoproxycreatorifnecessaryparsercontextobject-exc). Any Ideas would be more than helpful!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: so... you *know* that this will break with the current set-up and you are still asking here? makes little sense

Comment: I am asking because I still need to upgrade anyway. maybe someone else have faced something similar and had another setup using spring 4.